# Simulating a Coin toss

Tags: r, simulation

I am trying to simulate a coin toss using R. For that I used both `sample` function and `rbinom` function.

But I am getting different results.

```
> set.seed(1)
> rbinom(10,1,0.5)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0

> set.seed(1)
> sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE)
 [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
```

What may be the reason for that?

I thought for the same seed value, both sample function and rbinom should give the same result.

Comment: You have used the same seed, but the two procedures `rbinom` and `sample` use pseudorandom numbers in different ways.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965398/when-and-why-are-random-number-generators-not-sampled-for-certain-functions-and/64967064#64967064

Comment: You should mention your version of R because the default algorithm for `sample` has changed over time (IIRC most recently at 3.6.0).

Comment: A specific seed only reliably gives the same results when you call the exact same random functions in the exact same order (basically when you rerun the same code multiple times). Just because 2 functions output the same distribution of values for some sets of inputs doesn't mean what's happening behind the scenes is the same. This could even apply to functions that use the exact same high-level algorithm, since they could either use different lower-level random functions or the order they get their random values in might just not be the same.

Comment: Would this answer your question? [R Difference between rbinom and sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/339459/r-difference-between-rbinom-and-sample)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Somewhat related example:* One way to generate 10 tosses of a coin
with probability $0.4$ of heads is to use `rbinom`:

```
set.seed(123); rbinom(10, 1, .4)
[1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

Another way is to use the binomial inverse CDF (quantile) function) `qbinom` to transform uniform
random numbers from `runif` get the desired
Bernoulli distribution.

```
set.seed(123); qbinom(runif(10), 1, .4)
[1] 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

This suggests that R uses `qbinom` with `runif` to
get `rbinom`--in this instance.

However, for success probabilities greater than $0.5,$
it seems that R uses a variant of this method, and results starting with the same seed differ.

```
set.seed(123);  rbinom(10, 1, .6)
 [1] 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
set.seed(123);  qbinom(runif(10), 1, .6)
 [1] 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
```

If you use the same seed and you access pseudorandom numbers (as with `runif`) in exactly the same order
to do exactly the same procedure, you will get the same
result.

*Another example:* Means of 100 samples of size 10 from
the population $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 50, \sigma = 7).$

```
set.seed(1234)
a = replicate(100, mean(rnorm(10, 50, 7)))
summary(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  44.64   48.41   49.69   49.81   51.37   55.41 

set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(1000, 50, 7)
MAT = matrix(x, byrow = T, nrow=100)
a = rowMeans(MAT)
summary(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  44.64   48.41   49.69   49.81   51.37   55.41
```

However, if we omit `byrow=T` in making the matrix,
R will use its default, which is to fill the matrix by columns, and we will get a different summary (except, of course, for the mean of means).

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rnorm(1000, 50, 7)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=100)
a = rowMeans(MAT)
summary(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  42.80   48.47   49.80   49.81   51.20   55.27
```

Comment: For p > 0.5, the random numbers are drawn according to `size - rbinom(n, size, 1-p)` in case anyone wonders.

Answer (score 7):

An historical note about sample is that it [got recently modified](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.06520) for [being biased](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2019/05/21/biased-sample/) in some extreme situations (as commented by [Chris Haug](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/97510/chris-haug)). In earlier versions of R such as 3.4.4, still running on my ownlaptop, the outcome of the above would be the same as a cdf inversion (and as the complement of the standard Uniform draw):

```
> set.seed(1)
> rbinom(10,1,0.5)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0

> set.seed(1)
> sample(c(0,1), 10, replace = TRUE)
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0

> set.seed(1)
> qbinom(runif(10),1,0.5) #inverse cdf
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0

> set.seed(1)
> 1*(runif(10)>0.5) #complement!
 [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
```

When [checking the C code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/nmath/rbinom.c) behind the R function `rbinom`, the adopted approach relies on a single Uniform when $np<30$:

```
/* inverse cdf logic for mean less than 30 */
repeat {
 ix = 0;
 f = qn;
 u = unif_rand();
 repeat {
 if (u < f)
     goto finis;
 if (ix > 110)
     break;
 u -= f;
 ix++;
 f *= (g / ix - r);
```

and a much more involved resolution otherwise ($np\ge 30$), resolution including an accept-reject step,

```
/*------- np = n*p >= 30 : ----- */
repeat {
  u = unif_rand() * p4;
  v = unif_rand();
```

hence a random number of Uniforms. On the other hand, `sample` (in a version of 2017!) uses a [cascade of C functions](https://datascienceconfidential.github.io/r/2017/12/28/how-to-read-source-code-internal-r-function.html):

```
if (replace) {
    int i, nc = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) if(n * p[i] > 0.1) nc++;
    if (nc > 200)
    walker_ProbSampleReplace(n, p, INTEGER(x), k, INTEGER(y));
    else
    ProbSampleReplace(n, p, INTEGER(x), k, INTEGER(y));
} else
    ProbSampleNoReplace(n, p, INTEGER(x), k, INTEGER(y));
```

For instance, `ProbSampleReplace` is based on a single Uniform call:

```
/* compute the sample */
for (i = 0; i < nans; i++) {
  rU = unif_rand();
  for (j = 0; j < nm1; j++) {
      if (rU <= p[j])
```

and [the other ones](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/sugar/functions/sample.h) as well, which is not to say that they return the *same* outcome than `rbinom`!

Answer (score 2):

I tried getting to the source code for both, but couldn't find it.

I did, however, find the references for the building of the two algorithms.  They do not use the same references, so it is reasonable that they do not generate them in a similar manner.  Indeed, sample() function briefly says it uses an easier way to handle random numbers, presumably through different generation.